# What are the advantages of Sublime Text over Notepad++ and vice-versa?

Tags: editor, notepad++, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Lots of friends have suggested me to start using Sublime Text instead of Notepad++, but I've been happy so far with Notepad++. I use Notepad++ mainly for quick editing files (Haskell, Python, C#, HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), copying & paste pieces of text and running macros on it, etc.

What are the main differences in the feature set of Sublime Text and Notepad++?

Comment: I have made a discussion regarding this question on Meta [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196259/question-regarding-difference-between-two-tools-off-topic-but-why)

Comment: The biggest difference I've found is that Sublime has better-organized menus and a better default theme *(including that neat scrollbar)*, but Notepad++'s dialogs are superior.  The find/replace dialog *(my most used feature when editing text-files)* is so vastly inferior in Sublime that that sole feature is why I'm sticking with Notepad++ for now.

Comment: The only feature I love in ST2 thats missing in N++ is autocompletion of existing var names. BUT! The latest version of N++ has this now!!

Comment: Not a notepad++ comparison, but might want to see http://www.sitepoint.com/sitepoint-smackdown-atom-vs-brackets-vs-light-table-vs-sublime-text/

Comment: I was user of notepad++, now I've started using sublime and for me the MAIN greatest advantage is that Sublime Text use Python plugins, so writing extensions is clean and easy, that's why there are so many great plugins even though it is not free.

Comment: Sublime Text looks prettier... But I swapped back to Notepad++ for the reason @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft stated - Sublime doesn't select the "In selection" by default, even if text is selected when you start your search - there are bug reports of this on their forum since 2013.  Also Sublime can't print files...  I know it's not a massive deal these days, but...  really???

Comment: just a side note, since version 6.9 of Notepad++ (today 7.0 is the most up to date) they've put many new features in it, including the famous "tail", document tree, and working directory, as defaults, no plugin required, that kinda tilt the scales for now. it's just what a text editor needed. for me, October 2016, Notepad++ no doubt about it.  important to point out that both, still, don't support Right-To-Left languages, which is a huge drawback.

Answer (score 88):

One thing that should be considered is licensing.

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is free (as in speech and as in beer) for perpetual use, released under the [GPL license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.html), whereas Sublime Text 2 requires a license.

To quote the Sublime Text 2 [website](http://www.sublimetext.com/):

> ..a license must be purchased for continued use. There is currently no
>   enforced time limit for the evaluation.

The same is now true of Sublime Text 3, and a paid upgrade will be needed for future versions.

> **Upgrade Policy** 
>   A license is valid for Sublime Text 3, and includes all
>   point updates, as well as access to prior versions (e.g., Sublime Text
>   2). Future major versions, such as Sublime Text 4, will be a paid
>   upgrade.

This licensing requirement is still correct as of Dec 2019.

Comment: This is very important point. Currently Sublime Text 3 doesn't have free version

Comment: @TomWest Developers wouldn't allow unlimited evaluation periods unless they *expect* users who can't afford the software to carry on using it. You just wouldn't, would you?

Comment: We offer the unlimited eval for several reasons, the top one being marketing: Sublime Text's popularity is purely due to word of mouth amongst developers. Incidentally this also works out well for starving students, start-ups and novices who can't or won't pay but do have a presence on sites like this one to spread the word about Sublime. [- by SublimeHQ on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/1vqu4h/eli5_why_is_sublime_text_70/)

Answer (score 52):

Main advantage for me is that Sublime Text 2 is almost the same, and has the same features on Windows, Linux and OS X. Can you claim that about Notepad++? It makes me move from one OS to another seamlessly.

Then there is speed. Sublime Text 2, which people claim is buggy and unstable ( 3 is more stable ), is still amazingly fast. If you use it, you will realize how fast it is.

Sublime Text 2 has some neat features like multi cursor input, [multiple selections](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/editing/editing.html#multiple-selections) etc that will make you immensely productive.

Good number of plugins and themes, and also support for those of Textmate means you can do anything with Sublime Text 2. I have moved from Notepad++ to Sublime Text 2 on Windows and haven't looked back. The real question for me has been - Sublime Text 2 or vim?

What's good on Notepad++ side - it loads much faster on Windows for me. Maybe it will be good enough for you for quick editing. But, again, Sublime Text 3 is supposed to be faster on this front too. Sublime text 2 is not really good when it comes to handling huge files, and I had found that Notepad++ was pretty good till certain size of files. And, of course, Notepad++ is free. Sublime Text 2 has unlimited trial.

Comment: You lost me at *"Sublime Text 2 or vim."*

Comment: The newest Notepad++ versions also have multiple cursors (enable the feature in preferences, then ctrl-click to insert the cursors)

Comment: +1 to main advantage.  Also, Sublime Text seems to handle updates much much better than npp++ which often times wiped out customization & preferences.

Comment: That's a little bit bizarre. According to the author, Sublime Text 2 is the more stable one. Can you cite the source that says ST3 is more stable?

Comment: @JimRaynor Sublime Text 3 is still in Beta, that is why the author says its less stable than ST2 (it is being developed).
However, out of my experience (read with my computer, and usage style), ST3 is lighter, more robust and seems to handle lots of plugins better. But, again, this is my experience, no other source for this opinion.

Comment: Moving from one OS to another seamlessly... is that actually something you have to take into account? People are not moving to other OS all the time, are they?

Comment: @L-Three - I work on Windows, Ubuntu and OS X every week. Ubuntu and OS X for work, and Windows for my pet projects around C# and Powershell.

Comment: Sublime text + vintage mode is the answer

Comment: Notepad ++ can be run on Linux with an appimage - https://github.com/probonopd/libhookexecv/releases/continuous

Answer (score 8):

It's best if you judge on your own,

1) Sublime works on Mac & Linux that may be its plus point, with VI mode that makes things easily searchable for the VI lover(UNIX & Linux).

<strike>http://text-editors.findthebest.com/compare/9-45/Notepad-vs-Sublime-Text</strike>

This Link is no more working so please watch this video for similar details [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncWw2m6qUSc)

Initial observation revealed that everything else should work fine and almost similar;(with help of available plugins in notepad++)

Some Variation: Some user find plugins useful for PHP coders on that

http://codelikeapoem.com/2013/01/goodbye-notepad-hellooooo-sublime-text.html

although, there are many plugins for Notepad Plus Plus ..

I am not sure of your requirements, nor I am promoter of either of these editors :)

So, judge on basis of your requirements, this should satisfy you query...

Yes we can add that both are evolving and changing fast..

Comment: For PHP, PHPStorm wins hands down.   Notepad++ is cool because is free but if the money is not a problem then PHPStorm, the multicursor of Sublime Text can't compete with a proper refactor

Comment: @magallanes Thank you for the Update on PHPStorm, I need to agree on you comment but the question is not PHP specific so, I guess we can not say something specific to PHP only! The OP is looking for everything Haskell, Python, C#, HTML, JS, CSS, etc.

Comment: 1st link doesn't work any more

Comment: @Supersharp I have striked out that link and have added few more words.. :)